# Using CSS to transform list elements on hover

Tags: html, css, html-lists, transform

I've been having trouble making it so the links I have (which are nested in list elements) rotate when they're hovered over. I've been doing this:

```
li:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

I know the CSS is being applied, because the color changes. I know my syntax is correct, because when I tried the same thing, substituting `nav` for `li`, it worked. Is there a reason this won't work with `li`s in particular for some reason?

Comment: Can you fill a http://jsfiddle.net that shows your list and CSS not applyed correctly ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Unfortunately, no, because I'm using Ruby on Rails with things like Sass and embedded ruby. I phrased my question the way it would be were I just using CSS and HTML.

Comment: You could use Sass in codepen.io , if that helps to show us your trouble...

Comment: @GCyrillus The big thing is the embedded ruby. I'm not using one HTML page, I'm using two (one yielding to the other), and it's not all HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the li selectors in your css to link selectors, then add

```
display:inline-block;
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/xKNrQ/. You could just add the display property to the li selector, but then you'd have to use a separate rule to apply the color change for <a> tags.

Comment: Can you animate it on hover like sliding to down and should again slide up on mouse out by a fiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

Is your li set as a block element?

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/dQNFF/1/

I added this CSS:

```
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That works, but I need them inline. The solution then is `inline-block`.